# Как импортировать внешние библиотеки C# не создавая проект?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, библиотеки, импорт

как импортировать dll-библиотеку c# без создания проекта?

Пробовал через решения, не получилось :(

upd. У меня есть файл, в который нужно импортировать библиотеку с другого диска, и при этом не создавать проект. Импортировать надо в cs.
Не получилось добавить ссылку на библиотеку через решения VS.

Comment: Куда импортировать? Что сделать хотите? Что не получилось?

Comment: Проект - это система автоматичесеой сборки cs файлов (и не только). Ваш вопрос не имеет смысла, так как всё равно придется собрать приложение. А cs файл без проекта - это просто текстовый файл в нём просто текст, текст не может ничего импортировать. Решение - это набор проектов. Отсюда и получается в вашем вопросе как в том бреде про двух летящих крокодилов...